# Javascript: is this the right way to use a regular expression to replace multiple parts of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am curious about regular expressions and, being very new to programming I was wondering if there would be any problems (or a better way) of replacing different parts of the same string in this fashion:

```
str2.replace(/hanna/ig, 'clark').replace(/anna/ig, 'ark')
```

For example:

HTML:

```
<p id="test2" onClick="fixit2()">Hanna Hanna Bobanna Banana Nana Fo Fanna</p>
```

Javascript:

```
function fixit2()
{
var str2 = document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML;
    alert(str2);
    alert(str2.replace(/hanna/ig, 'clark').replace(/anna/ig, 'ark'));
}
```

I have been working on it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/A2Lkd/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it achieves what you want there is no problem... Using regular expressions to replace patterns in strings is a very common practice. However you should always make sure that the regular expression you are using is the right one for the task. Please note that strings are immutable and a new string is returned from the `replace` operations. The original string will not get modified.